# Array.sort works differently in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, firefox, cross-browser

This question has been asked various times, but in most of the questions the person asking is doing something wrong.

Examples:

[Array.sort working differently in chrome and firefox and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832158/array-sort-working-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox-and-ie)

[JavaScript. Array .sort() method returns different results for Chrome and Firefox if array contains duplicate numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40516590/javascript-array-sort-method-returns-different-results-for-chrome-and-firefo)

[Array.sort() behaves differently in Firefox and Chrome/Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039157/array-sort-behaves-differently-in-firefox-and-chrome-edge)

Hopefully in my case, I'm doing something wrong as well. But the evidence against the browsers is pretty damning!

When you view the table in my website, it is sorted in opposite orders on Firefox and Chrome.

Here is my code:

```
function sortByKey(a, b) {
    console.log(`b: ${b.id} - a: ${a.id}`);
    return b[SORTING_KEY] - a[SORTING_KEY];
}

export function sortObjectValues(mappedObject) {
    console.log('BEGIN SORTING');
    return Object.values(mappedObject)
        .sort(sortByKey);
}
```

Here is the log output in Chrome:

```
BEGIN SORTING
b: 7920 - a: 7924
b: 7924 - a: 7931
b: 7920 - a: 7931
b: 7924 - a: 7931
b: 7931 - a: 7942
b: 7920 - a: 7942
b: 7942 - a: 7945
b: 7931 - a: 7945
b: 7924 - a: 7945
b: 7931 - a: 7952
b: 7945 - a: 7952
b: 7924 - a: 7952
b: 7931 - a: 7953
b: 7920 - a: 7953
b: 7942 - a: 7953
b: 7931 - a: 7959
b: 7924 - a: 7959
b: 7945 - a: 7959
b: 7931 - a: 9185
b: 7959 - a: 9185
b: 7924 - a: 9185
b: 7952 - a: 9185
b: 7945 - a: 9189
b: 7924 - a: 9189
b: 7952 - a: 9189
b: 9185 - a: 9189
```

And here is the output in Firefox:

```
BEGIN SORTING
b: 7924 - a: 7920
b: 7931 - a: 7920
b: 7931 - a: 7924
b: 7942 - a: 7920
b: 7942 - a: 7931
b: 7945 - a: 7920
b: 7945 - a: 7942
b: 7945 - a: 7931
b: 7945 - a: 7924
b: 7952 - a: 7920
b: 7952 - a: 7942
b: 7952 - a: 7931
b: 7952 - a: 7945
b: 7952 - a: 7924
b: 7953 - a: 7920
b: 7953 - a: 7942
b: 7953 - a: 7931
b: 7959 - a: 7920
b: 7959 - a: 7942
b: 7959 - a: 7953
b: 7959 - a: 7931
b: 7959 - a: 7945
b: 7959 - a: 7924
b: 9185 - a: 7920
b: 9185 - a: 7942
b: 9185 - a: 7953
b: 9185 - a: 7931
b: 9185 - a: 7945
b: 9185 - a: 7959
b: 9185 - a: 7924
b: 9185 - a: 7952
b: 9189 - a: 7920
b: 9189 - a: 7942
b: 9189 - a: 7953
b: 9189 - a: 7931
b: 9189 - a: 7945
b: 9189 - a: 7959
b: 9189 - a: 7924
b: 9189 - a: 7952
b: 9189 - a: 9185
```

To me, it seems like the order of the arguments has been reversed in Firefox. What is going on here??

Chrome userAgent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36`

Firefox userAgent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0`

When logging `SORTING_KEY` along with id, I get:

Chrome

```
BEGIN SORTING
b: SORTING_KEY=0 id=7920 - a: SORTING_KEY=6 id=7924
b: SORTING_KEY=6 id=7924 - a: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931
b: SORTING_KEY=0 id=7920 - a: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931
b: SORTING_KEY=6 id=7924 - a: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931
b: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931 - a: SORTING_KEY=1 id=7942
b: SORTING_KEY=0 id=7920 - a: SORTING_KEY=1 id=7942
b: SORTING_KEY=1 id=7942 - a: SORTING_KEY=4 id=7945
b: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931 - a: SORTING_KEY=4 id=7945
b: SORTING_KEY=6 id=7924 - a: SORTING_KEY=4 id=7945
b: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931 - a: SORTING_KEY=7 id=7952
b: SORTING_KEY=4 id=7945 - a: SORTING_KEY=7 id=7952
b: SORTING_KEY=6 id=7924 - a: SORTING_KEY=7 id=7952
b: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931 - a: SORTING_KEY=2 id=7953
b: SORTING_KEY=0 id=7920 - a: SORTING_KEY=2 id=7953
b: SORTING_KEY=1 id=7942 - a: SORTING_KEY=2 id=7953
b: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931 - a: SORTING_KEY=5 id=7959
b: SORTING_KEY=6 id=7924 - a: SORTING_KEY=5 id=7959
b: SORTING_KEY=4 id=7945 - a: SORTING_KEY=5 id=7959
b: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931 - a: SORTING_KEY=9 id=9185
b: SORTING_KEY=5 id=7959 - a: SORTING_KEY=9 id=9185
b: SORTING_KEY=6 id=7924 - a: SORTING_KEY=9 id=9185
b: SORTING_KEY=7 id=7952 - a: SORTING_KEY=9 id=9185
b: SORTING_KEY=4 id=7945 - a: SORTING_KEY=8 id=9189
b: SORTING_KEY=6 id=7924 - a: SORTING_KEY=8 id=9189
b: SORTING_KEY=7 id=7952 - a: SORTING_KEY=8 id=9189
b: SORTING_KEY=9 id=9185 - a: SORTING_KEY=8 id=9189
```

Firefox

```
BEGIN SORTING
b: SORTING_KEY=6 id=7924 - a: SORTING_KEY=0 id=7920
b: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931 - a: SORTING_KEY=0 id=7920
b: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931 - a: SORTING_KEY=6 id=7924
b: SORTING_KEY=1 id=7942 - a: SORTING_KEY=0 id=7920
b: SORTING_KEY=1 id=7942 - a: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931
b: SORTING_KEY=4 id=7945 - a: SORTING_KEY=0 id=7920
b: SORTING_KEY=4 id=7945 - a: SORTING_KEY=1 id=7942
b: SORTING_KEY=4 id=7945 - a: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931
b: SORTING_KEY=4 id=7945 - a: SORTING_KEY=6 id=7924
b: SORTING_KEY=7 id=7952 - a: SORTING_KEY=0 id=7920
b: SORTING_KEY=7 id=7952 - a: SORTING_KEY=1 id=7942
b: SORTING_KEY=7 id=7952 - a: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931
b: SORTING_KEY=7 id=7952 - a: SORTING_KEY=4 id=7945
b: SORTING_KEY=7 id=7952 - a: SORTING_KEY=6 id=7924
b: SORTING_KEY=2 id=7953 - a: SORTING_KEY=0 id=7920
b: SORTING_KEY=2 id=7953 - a: SORTING_KEY=1 id=7942
b: SORTING_KEY=2 id=7953 - a: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931
b: SORTING_KEY=5 id=7959 - a: SORTING_KEY=0 id=7920
b: SORTING_KEY=5 id=7959 - a: SORTING_KEY=1 id=7942
b: SORTING_KEY=5 id=7959 - a: SORTING_KEY=2 id=7953
b: SORTING_KEY=5 id=7959 - a: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931
b: SORTING_KEY=5 id=7959 - a: SORTING_KEY=4 id=7945
b: SORTING_KEY=5 id=7959 - a: SORTING_KEY=6 id=7924
b: SORTING_KEY=9 id=9185 - a: SORTING_KEY=0 id=7920
b: SORTING_KEY=9 id=9185 - a: SORTING_KEY=1 id=7942
b: SORTING_KEY=9 id=9185 - a: SORTING_KEY=2 id=7953
b: SORTING_KEY=9 id=9185 - a: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931
b: SORTING_KEY=9 id=9185 - a: SORTING_KEY=4 id=7945
b: SORTING_KEY=9 id=9185 - a: SORTING_KEY=5 id=7959
b: SORTING_KEY=9 id=9185 - a: SORTING_KEY=6 id=7924
b: SORTING_KEY=9 id=9185 - a: SORTING_KEY=7 id=7952
b: SORTING_KEY=8 id=9189 - a: SORTING_KEY=0 id=7920
b: SORTING_KEY=8 id=9189 - a: SORTING_KEY=1 id=7942
b: SORTING_KEY=8 id=9189 - a: SORTING_KEY=2 id=7953
b: SORTING_KEY=8 id=9189 - a: SORTING_KEY=3 id=7931
b: SORTING_KEY=8 id=9189 - a: SORTING_KEY=4 id=7945
b: SORTING_KEY=8 id=9189 - a: SORTING_KEY=5 id=7959
b: SORTING_KEY=8 id=9189 - a: SORTING_KEY=6 id=7924
b: SORTING_KEY=8 id=9189 - a: SORTING_KEY=7 id=7952
b: SORTING_KEY=8 id=9189 - a: SORTING_KEY=9 id=9185
```

Map of `id` to `SORTING_KEY` is identical between the two browsers:

```
7920: 0
7924: 6
7931: 3
7942: 1
7945: 4
7952: 7
7953: 2
7959: 5
9185: 9
9189: 8
```

Comment: You should search what is the algo of firefox sort and google sort

Comment: Both give you the same result no? The sorting algorithm isn't standardized by the spec.

Comment: @mehdim2 it's not the algorithm- looks to me like the arguments are being applied in different orders??

Comment: Sorry, should have specified, the outcome in my browser is that table rows are sorted in reverse order on Firefox (compared to what renders in Chrome)

Comment: Most likely `SORTING_KEY` is not what you think it is then.

Comment: @MinusFour actually, to debug, I added a column to the table that displays the value of SORTING_KEY for each row. The values are the same for each object in Chrome and Firefox. The sorting order just comes out reversed.

Comment: Could you print `b[SORTING_KEY]` and `a[SORTING_KEY]` instead of `b.id` and `a.id`?

Comment: @MinusFour Good idea. Added logs with `id` and `SORTING_KEY` for more clarity

Comment: UPDATE: the issue with sorting the tables actually had to do with the Table component using `Array.sort` internally with no arguments. Stupid.